# text "jumping" in scrjura

Tags: positioning, koma-script, scrjura

Sorry for the weird title, didn't know how to better describe it.

I have an issue with scrjura and the beginning of new lines. They don't start at the same point, below is an image of what I mean.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[juratotoc]{scrjura} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand*{\parformat}{% 
  \global\hangindent 2em 
  \makebox[2em][l]{(\thepar)\hfill}\hspace{-0,3cm} 
} 
\makeatother 

\begin{document} 
\addchap{Vertrag blabla} 
\begin{contract} 
\Clause{title={Vertragsgegenstand}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.

Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.

Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.

Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.

Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.

\end{contract} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Problem]

Anyone any idea as to why this is happening and how to remove it?

If I leave away the `\renewcommand*{\parformat}`... part, it still happens, just without the indent, so that appears not to be the issue:

[image: Problem2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to redefine `\parformatseparation` too. Its original definition is `\nobreakspace`.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}[2016/05/10] 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[juratotoc]{scrjura} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand*{\parformat}{% 
  \global\hangindent 2em 
  \makebox[2em][l]{(\thepar)\hfill}%<- the % is needed here
}
\makeatother 
\renewcommand*{\parformatseparation}{}

\begin{document} 
\addchap{Vertrag blabla} 
\begin{contract} 
\Clause{title={Vertragsgegenstand}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.

Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.

Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.

Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.

Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.

\end{contract} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you, your image looks great, I want that too :D Unfortunately I'm getting the error:
\parformatseparation undefined. \renewcommand *{\parformatseparation}

I'm probably doing something wrong... Do you have an idea what that would be?

Comment: Which KOMA-Script Version do you use? My suggestion needs 3.20 or newer. Current version on CTAN and in the distributions is 3.22

Comment: Forgot to answer: the version I used was too old. It worked perfectly with a newer version, thank you!!